# Новый WebGL у Unity 5.6 пустая сцена при переключении

Tags: unity3d

После обновления Unity на версию 5.6.1f возникла проблема в WebGL билде.

При использовании

```
SceneManager.LoadScene
```

или

```
SceneManagerLoadSceneAcynh
```

Открывается сцена, но на ней только те объекты, которые DontDestroyOnLoad c предыдущей сцены.

Т.е. сцена пустая, даже камеры нет, черный экран. 
Ошибок никаких нет, даже с Develop и DebugSumbols.

Видел подобное в англоязычном сегменте, но там так и не дали ответа на вопрос
https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/black-screen-when-changing-scene-in-webgl-using-unity-5-6.473367/

Comment: А зачем обновлялись? На старой можно оставаться? Если да, то откатывайтесь и ждите патча имхо...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Довольно неочевидное решение - необходимо в Build Settings выбрать платформу Андроид, и не переключаясь туда, снять галочку "Split Application Binary".

Теперь сцены в WebGL билде будут загружаться корректно.